# Resize / enlarge array and populate with NAs in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I want to enlarge an array in R where the extra cells are `NA`s (or something).

The only way I can find to do this is to create a new `NA`-filled array in the larger size, then over-write it with the old data, e.g.:

```
old.data <- array(data=seq(1,24),dim=c(2,3,4))

new.data <- array(data=NA, dim=c(dim(old.data)[1]+1, # adding e.g. 1 extra row
                                 dim(old.data)[2],
                                 dim(old.data)[3]))

new.data[1:dim(old.data)[1],,] <- old.data
```

This works, but feels sub-optimal.

Better ideas?

Comment: I think yours is a good way to do it.

Comment: I agree, this looks efficient. However, have a look at `library(abind); ?abind` for a convenience function.

Comment: A more general (although not more efficient) way could be `new.data[arrayInd(seq_along(old.data),dim(old.data))]<-old.data`, that allows you to enhance any dimension of whatever amount.

Comment: And you can reduce the repetition of `dim(old.data)` by just adding a vector to `dim(old.data)` (like `dim(old.data) + c(1, 0, 0)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```
library(magrittr)

lapply(split(old.data, rep(1:12, each=2)), c, NA) %>% unlist %>% array(dim=c(3,3,4))

#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    2    4    6
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    7    9   11
#[2,]    8   10   12
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA

#, , 3

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   13   15   17
#[2,]   14   16   18
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA

#, , 4

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   19   21   23
#[2,]   20   22   24
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```